# how to create the surface with P3 colorspace use EGL extension

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl

I want to use EGL to create a surface with a wide color gamut such as P3, I read the following guide.
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/wide-color-photos-are-coming-to-android.html
https://developer.android.com/training/wide-color-gamut

Following is the code I write in native to create a surface with P3

```
std::vector<EGLint> attributes;
attributes.push_back(EGL_GL_COLORSPACE_KHR);
attributes.push_back(EGL_GL_COLORSPACE_DISPLAY_P3_EXT);
attributes.push_back(EGL_NONE);
surface_ = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, window, attributes.data());
```

Then weird things happened, when I run my program on Pixel2 (Android 9), it works, and can create the surface with correct colorspace, but when I run on Pixel2 (Android 10), it failed to create surface。

```
2020-03-04 19:11:05.547 1146-1275/com.example.widecolor E/libEGL: processAttributes:604 error 3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
2020-03-04 19:11:05.547 1146-1275/com.example.widecolor E/libEGL: error invalid colorspace: 13155
```

I think the difference is the EGL version, Android 9 use EGL1.4, when Android 10 use EGL 1.5. The question is how I can create EGL surface with wide color space under Android 10.